# How (is it possible) to create an hg command alias that runs multiple commands?

Tags: mercurial

I would like to define a Mercurial command alias in my hgrc file that invokes multiple commands. For example I would like to do something like the following:

```
[alias]
giveup = revert --all --no-backup; purge
syncprod = fetch production; push production
```

This would allow me to call `hg syncprod` and have it invoke a fetch and then a push. Haven't been able to determine if this capability exists. (I'm guessing that means no.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the shell alias style like this:

```
giveup = !$HG revert --all --no-backup ; $HG purge
```

Though, personally I'd just create a bash alias for those so I could skip the `hg` part altogether.

Comment: Forking useful! I found myself typing `hg up -C && hg purge` way too often.

Answer (score 12):

To do this on Windows, the following syntax worked for me, without having to use PowerShell or cygwin.

```
giveup = !hg revert --all --no-backup && hg purge
```

Alternatively, this version will execute the purge regardless of whether the revert was successful:

```
giveup = !hg revert --all --no-backup & hg purge
```

It is possible to string together more than two commands, for instance:

```
shebase = !hg shelve && hg rebase && hg unshelve
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can call powershell or cmd from the alias. E.g. I use following
> alias with powershell:
>
> ```
> amend = !powershell -NoProfile -Command hg ci -m $(cat .hg\last-message.txt)
> ```

(Comment left by Bozydar Sobczak  Apr 7, 2012)