# Pushing and pulling with hgsubversion without manual shelve step

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgsubversion

I'm using TortoiseHg with an SVN repository using the hgsubversion extension.

I like to use `hg pull --rebase` when I pull, to mirror what SVN does on `svn update`. Because I'm using hgsubversion, I will need to rebase anyway before I push, so I may as well do it in one step.

Additionally, `hg push` will *automatically* do a rebase internally, there is no way around that.

My difficulty is that `hg rebase` will refuse to work if I have any uncommitted changes. So to push or pull from SVN I always need to `hg shelve` first and then remember to do `hg unshelve` after. This can get really annoying and I always forget.

Ideally I'd like to tell TortoiseHg to do this for me automatically, but I'd settle for a command-line alias. I tried putting an alias like `svnpull = !hg shelve && hg pull --rebase && hg unshelve` in my config [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29144314/1390430) but I get an error "user: abort: response expected" instead of being asked for my password. What can I do to avoid manually shelve/unshelve steps every time I interact with the central repository?

I *can't* actually commit my changes locally and just avoid pushing the local change, because [hgsubversion doesn't respect the *secret* phase](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/issues/382/outgoing-push-ignore-secret-phase) and [hgsubversion doesn't support designating a revision to push](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/issues/243/hg-push-r-rev-to-subversion-does-not-only). So unfortunately none of the answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9207762/1390430) will work for me. And anyway I'd need manual steps to arrange for my "local only" changeset to always be on the tip.

Comment: Is it http-based SVN-repository?

Comment: Yes, it is http based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use repository hooks. I added this to my .hg/hgrc config file:

```
[hooks]
pre-pull = hg shelve
post-pull = hg unshelve
pre-push = hg shelve
post-push = hg unshelve
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't enter password manually, automate it with keyring (questionable on Windows) or using `[auth]` section of in [project's .hgrc](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth)

Sample from my local hg-repo for remote SVN-backend

```
[auth]
assembla.prefix = https://subversion.assembla.com
assembla.username = USER
assembla.password = PASSWORD
```

and entering password not needed anymore

Another idea: you haven't push immediatelly your WIP, yes? You have only to have it on top of "other" work, true? You *can* in this case commit, rebase, and continue to work with the same `tip`, modifying it with `commit --amend`

Comment: I really don't want to save my password in plain text, so I don't like using the [auth] section in this way. And I'm mostly wanting to have some local changes which will NEVER be committed, such as turning off compiler optimization in the makefile for debugging purposes.